# PHP: How to convert escaped characters to plain text without str_replace

Tags: php, string, whitespace, html-escape-characters

Convert escaped characters/ whitespaces to plain text

I received data from another database and want to data as plain text.

For now it is using \n, \v,\e, \t, etc as escaped characters. But I want to use it as a text.
I don't want to use `str_replace`, `preg_replace`.
So how to achieve the solution for this

**Output should be like below**

**Example:**

```
echo $abc;
```

**Output:**

```
Abc\n\tasd
```

Comment: Most APIs return JSON, and `json_decode()` will convert the escaped characters. What API returns these literally and requires you to parse them?

Comment: Is there a way to assign php variable in single quote as single quote ignore escaped characters?

Comment: I apparently misunderstood the question. You don't want to parse the escape sequences, you want to see the escape sequences. So the returned data doesn't contain the escape sequences, it contains the actual control characters.

Comment: See [addcslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php)

Comment: Yes, you are right I want the same text as it is getting. Not want \n \t etc to work as escaped chars

Comment: I can understand not wanting to use preg_repalce.  But who could have anything against str_replace??  So you are looking for an alternative to valid solutions? I'm offended. str_replace is my friend. I use her often.  I know the answer but you insulted my friend.

Comment: @Misunderstood sorry for that. But I didn't insulted str_replace. As str_replace is used for the only characters I added to it so thats why I want the alternate solution. Please answer the question. I will thankful to you

Comment: @Barmar its not working for the same

Comment: @AkJosh Don't be dismissive of BarMar he is one of the smartest on this forum.  Conversion is very simple.  You just make a list of the replacements in an array.  Then use the array to make the replacements with my friend str_replace. I wasn't rerally insulted I was just trying to be humorous. I mean I do not have a drinking problem, but when I drink (like very night) I become a different person.  That person has a drinking problem.  One thing though I do not understand why this is a problem?  Why did you not think str_replace could not help?

Comment: If you want to display strings with special characters for debugging purposes, then take a look at this class https://github.com/jspit-de/Debug

Answer (score 2):

Use [`addcslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php)

```
$abc = "foo\nbar\txyz";
 
echo addcslashes($abc, "\n\t\e\v\r");
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/Iqmmub)

Comment: Its not working for \e

Comment: try  addcslashes($string,"\x00..\x1f");

Comment: \e is represented as "\033", which is the same.

Comment: @AkJosh Did you add it to the second argument? That tells the function which characters it should replace (I linked to the documentation so you would understand how to use it).